# How to find number which is greater?

Tags: number-theory

I have two numbers $\left(\frac{8}{7}\right)^{\frac{7}{8}}$ & $\left(\frac{9}{8}\right)^{\frac{8}{9}}$. How to find out the greater number?

I am 12th grad. thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you thought about the function $x^{1/x}$?

Comment: If you were in the UK I would suggest seeing whether $f(x)=x^{1/x}$ was an increasing function for these numbers, perhaps by taking the logarithm before differentiating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said, consider the function $$f(x)=\left({1 \over x}\right)^x$$
Take the derivative to find where it is increasing or decreasing $$f'(x) = {d\over dx}(x^{-x})={d\over dx}(e^{-xln(x)})=-x^{-x}{d\over dx}(xln(x))=-x^{-x}(1+ln(x))$$
We can see that when $ln(x)=-1, x=e^{-1},$ and $f(x)=0$

by inspection we can see that when $$x>e^{-1}, f'(x)<0$$ $$e^{-1}<\frac78<\frac89$$

so $f(x)$ is decreasing at the points of interest $$\Rightarrow f\left(\frac78\right)>f\left(\frac89\right)$$ or as desired $$\left(\frac87\right)^{\frac78}>\left(\frac98\right)^{\frac89}$$

Comment: your answer helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you know calculus, consider the function $$f(x) = (1/x)^x = \frac{1}{x^x}$$ Can you see if it is increasing or decreasing in $x$?

**UPDATE**

- How do you prove that a function is increasing (what must happen to its derivative)?
- Can you prove $g(x) = \ln f(x) = -x \ln x$ is increasing?
- Can you conclude from this, that $f(x)$ is also increasing?
- your problem boils down to comparing $f(7/8)$ and $f(8/9)$

Comment: I am unable to proceed further. Could you please give further hint?

Comment: @Bhaskara-III do you know calculus -- derivatives?

Comment: yes that I know well

Comment: @Bhaskara-III see update

Comment: @Winther thank you, fixed

Answer (score 2):

You want to compare
$\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^{(n-1)/n}$
and
$\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n/(n+1)}$
for
$n=8$.

In the following
"$?$" is "<" or ">".
I want to determine which
"?" is.

$\begin{array}\\
\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^{(n-1)/n}
?
\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n/(n+1)}
&\iff 
\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^{(n-1)(n+1)}
?
\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\\
&\iff 
\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^{n^2-1}
?
\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\\
&\iff 
\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^{-1}
?
\left(\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}\\
&\iff 
1-\frac{1}{n}
?
\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}
\approx 1/e
$,
and
$1-1/n > 1/e$,
we expect that
"?" is ">".
Proving this
only needs
$-\ln(1-x) > x$
for
$0 < x < 1$.

$(1-1/n^2)^{-n^2}
=\exp(-n^2\ln(1-1/n^2))
>\exp(n^2(1/n^2))
=\exp(1)
$
or
$(1-1/n^2)^{n^2}
< 1/e
$.

Since
$1-1/n >
1/e
$
for $n \ge 2$.
and
$(1-1/n^2)^{n^2}
< 1/e
$,
$1-1/n
>(1-1/n^2)^{n^2}
$.

Therefore
"?" is
">",
and
$\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^{(n-1)/n}
>
\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n/(n+1)}
$.

As a check
$(8/7)^{7/8}
\approx 1.124
$
and
$(9/8)^{8/9}
\approx 1.110
$.